# Phonegap button onclick on Ios

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova

I have a app in android devices with phonegap, and his work fine.

The ios version have a problem with firing javascript function on click button.
I use angularjs:

```
<button class="grabar" ng-click="recordSound()">Grabar</button>
```

This button don't work in Ios version but work in android.

Without angular (onclick=...), have a same problem..

Need make this without jquery.

Thanks!

PD: I see an example use this trick:

```
<a href="javascript:recordSound()">Record</a><br/>
```

And his work fine! -_- But not is the good way I think.. it's more fine with button.

Pd2: Ok! I resolve the problem using:

```
<button class="grabar" onclick="recordSound();">Grabar</button>
```

But I not understand why not work ng-click.

Comment: Did you try: ...ng-click="recordSound();">

Comment: Thanks tpdietz bt not work